# How to delete mails except the latest one?

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to clean my mailbox that's why I need to write something on VBA,
The issue below, the dictionary (as far i understand) is not working properly,

basically the codes should delete mails except the latest one.
-- one mail(inbox) might have many reply with the history of mail issue. the macro should check the mail.receivedtime and delete the items except the latest one.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateItems()
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim olNs As NameSpace

    Dim i As Long
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim strKey As String
    Dim zaman As Date


    Dim olFld As Folder
    MailboxName = "test@test.com"
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFld = olNs.Folders(MailboxName).Folders("Inbox")
    Set tasima = olNs.Folders(MailboxName).Folders("Inbox").Folders("Old")

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder

    If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
       For i = objFolder.items.Count To 1 Step -1
           Set objItem = objFolder.items.item(i)

           Select Case objFolder.DefaultItemType
                  Case olMailItem
                       strKey = objItem.Subject
            End Select

           strKey = Replace(strKey, ", ", Chr(32))


           If objDictionary.Exists(strKey) Then
           'do nothing'
            Else
           objDictionary.Add strKey, objItem.ReceivedTime
           End If
       Next i
    End If



    For Each olitem In objFolder.items
        If TypeName(olitem) = "MailItem" Then
            If objDictionary.Exists(olitem.Subject) Then
                If olitem.ReceivedTime > objDictionary(strKey) Then

            Debug.Print olitem
            Debug.Print olitem.ReceivedTime
            olitem.Move tasima


                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i = objFolder.items.Count To 1 Step -1
   Set objItem = objFolder.items.item(i)
```

Iterating through all items in the folder is not really a good idea. Instead, you may sort items in the folder by the `ReceivedTime` and get the latest one - the first or last item in the `Items` collection depending on the sort order used.

See the [Items.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) methods which sort the collection of items by the specified property. The index for the collection is reset to 1 upon completion of this method.